# Different values of mouseEvent.offsetY in Windows 8+ and 7 of IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-8, mouseevent, onmouseout

I am facing a problem when I am trying to detect that mouse has been moved upward or downward when `mouseleave` event fires on the document using offsetY value.
Ideally it should be negative while mouse has been moved to upward direction and positive while mouse has been moved to downward direction (Working fine in Chrome/Firefox/IE of Windows 7) but not in IE's of Windows 8+.

In IE's of Windows 8+, it is always returning the positive value irrespective of direction.

Why it is behaving so weird?

Any suggestion for detecting it (Expect the hacks)

My code:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', function (e) {
    if(e.offsetY < 0) {
         //Do something
    }
});
```

EDIT: I am basically doing it for detecting if the user is trying to close the page or want to change the browser tab.